# Add Style toolbar to Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, toolbar, styles

Before Word 2007, it was possible to add a custom toolbar to Word with a number of **style** buttons on it (for example: Heading 1, Heading 2, Body Text, List Bullet, ...).

This made it easy to see and use the styles that had to be used for a document (or template).

As I've understood that Word 2007 doesn't (easily) allow to add toolbars, is there any alternative in Word 2007 to get similar functionality?

Solution: 
as it isn't really obvious from the answer below: the 'Styles' section in the Home tab contains a 'Style Set Gallery'. The styles that are included in this gallery can be customized through the use of Style Sets (Change Styles > Style Sets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word 2007 has the "Styles" section in the Home tab that should have the exact same functions as you want.

[image]

Comment: No, it does not, because it contains styles I don't want to use in a document. In Word 2003 and earlier it was possible to create a toolbar with ONLY the styles that had to be used in a document.

Comment: Hmm, seems I jumped to conclusions to quickly. Indeed, one can create a 'Style Set' and add and remove certain stylesfrom the Style Set Gallery.

Comment: However, after more than 2 years, I should say that I don't like to use it (and haven't really).

Answer (score 0):

The [Quick] Styles Gallery only shows the styles designated to appear in that gallery, usually less than twenty of the more than a hundred styles. The Dialog Launcher (little arrow in the bottom-right corner of the Styles gallery) lets you launch the Styles Pane which gives much more control. From there, using the Manage Styles button, you can display all of your styles in that pane and choose how they are sorted. See [Manage Styles](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, Word MVP.

In addition, you can add the styles dropdown from the menu version to your QAT. To sample this without the work, use the [Styles QAT Add-In](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#StylesQATAddIn) from my site.

[image: Styles controls in the QAT]